# Symfony: how to add validation group to RepeatedType?

Tags: symfony

How to add validation group to RepeatedType? I want to enable RepeatedType validation for specific group only (ex. 'updatePasswords') like during the constraint validation.

Here's my form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('updatePasswordCheckBox', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat password'),
                'invalid_message' => "Passwords don't match!",
                'groups' => "updatePasswordChecked",

            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'));
    }
```

UPDATE:
Depending on the status of the password checkbox the corresponding validation group will be triggered:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class'        => 'ImmoBundle\Entity\User',
                'csrf_protection'   => true,
                'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form){
                    $data = $form->getData();

                    if ($data->getUpdatePasswordCheckBox() == 1)
                    {
                        return array('Default', 'updatePasswordChecked');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return array('Default', 'update');
                    }
                }
            ));
    }
```

Comment: what happens when the password checkbox is not checked ? do you send the old password in request or empty string or what ?

Comment: When password checkbox is not checked the password validation should not happen. That's what I'm actually trying to do
PS. I've updated my question.

Comment: when you say RepeatedType Validation, you mean validating that the two fields are the same, or do you mean password validation like min/max lenght... ?

Comment: I mean the validation that two fields are the same

Comment: Did you add a custom field to your User Entity?